# In Lanthanides, Why is electron removed from 4f before 5p?

Tags: electronic-configuration, atoms, oxidation-state, rare-earth-elements

I've been taught that electrons are removed first from valence shell electrons with highest energy. But In Lanthanides, for example taking configuration- [Xe]4f⁴6s², If we go to +3 Oxidation State, then the configuration is [Xe]4f³.
But valence shell is 5th, so why wasn't electron removed from 5p instead of 4f?

Comment: 5p electrons have significantly lower energy than 6s and 4f. 4f orbitals are being filled after 5p and 6s. Remember that with advent of d and f orbitals, the single valence shell number does not apply much.